# how to get date of out of stock product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, orders, out-of-stock

I need the date of out of stock product.

is this possible we get the date of product when the product is out of stock or again quantity added in stock?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I get the date of out of stock products in column `low_stock_date` of this table `cataloginventory_stock_item` from databse.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT cataloginventory_stock_item.product_id, cataloginventory_stock_item.low_stock_date, catalog_product_entity.sku FROM cataloginventory_stock_item INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity ON (cataloginventory_stock_item.product_id= catalog_product_entity.entity_id AND cataloginventory_stock_item.qty= 0 AND (cataloginventory_stock_item.low_stock_date BETWEEN '2017-12-19 00:00:01' AND '2017-12-19 23:59:59'))
```

i get product id, SKU and date of out of stock product by above query.

And in Magento way:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach($collection as $product){

$productid = $product->getId();
$productsku = $product->getSku();
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getIsInStock();
$lowstockdate = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getLowStockDate();

        if($stock == 0 ){
            echo $product->getSku()." = ";
            echo $product->getName()." = ";
            echo $lowstockdate."<br>";


        }

}
```

Comment: Could you share how you do that in you code?

Comment: sure.... @Anime i updated my answer please check.

Comment: Please accept my answer to help others.@Anime

Comment: That does not seem magento preferred way.

Comment: ok i will try to get it in magento way. @Anime Thanks

Comment: hi @Anime i get the out of stock date in magento way. Please check my edited answer.